# Serverless-AWS Lambda-Typescript-How do I include additional scripts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm very new to this area. I created the below folder structure:

```
Serverless
    serverless.yml
    function1.ts
    models1.ts
    models2.ts
    <other json, config files>
```

The `models` files have shared code between different functions. I already installed `serverless-webpack` and other `webpack`. I also added the below into the `.yml` file:

```
service:
  name: myapi

package:
  include:
    - models1.ts
    - models2.ts
```

When I run `serverless package`, I can see `function1.ts` get compiled into `.js` file and included in `.serverless`'s `.zip` file, but I don't see the `models` files get compiled. How do I get that work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to include the `models1.ts` and `models2.ts`

you can use this plugin https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

if you want those models to be included inside the generated bundle we need to make sure that your import resolution on webapck is well configured.